# How to use List in reports

Tags: apex, community, reporting, customlabel

i got a requirement in which I want to filter a report of opportunities based on a list of users.

My list of users shuffles frequently. I have created a custom label with users names. So we are modifying this label whenever any member is shuffles from the team.

So, I try to filter opportunities owner with this label. So, I created a formula field to get data from custom label. But I can't filter with values.

Please suggest any better idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Adrian Larson i have seen your answer with custom permission.But i don't know why u deleted that answer may be your solution very helpful in my case.Can you share your answer once again.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a formula (return type Checkbox):

```
CONTAINS($Label.ListOfUsers, Owner.Name)
```

Which you could then filter in the report:

```
Owner Matches List equals true
```

Comment: Hey But the problem is I have 4 other teams also there.So i have to create four other formula fields i think it is not a best practice.Is there any possibility to use opportunity owner equals group. @sfdcfox